# docker-java equivalent of "docker service create --with-registry-auth"

Tags: docker, docker-java

Using https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java and looking for a way to add the `--with-registry-auth` option from https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#options

```java
val createCmd = dockerClient.createServiceCmd(
                ServiceSpec()
                        .withName("name")

                        .withTaskTemplate(TaskSpec()
                                .withContainerSpec(ContainerSpec()
                                        .withEnv(envs)
                                        .withImage("image")
                                        .withMounts(mounts)
                                )
                                .withNetworks(networks)
                                .withPlacement(ServicePlacement()
                                        .withConstraints(constraints))
                        )
        )
```

To clarify this more:

I am looking for docker-java way to do this command (this does work!):

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --constraint 'node.labels.mynodeid==7' myprivateregistry.foo:5000/imagename:latest
```

Removing the `--with-registry-auth` like this

```
docker service create --constraint 'node.labels.mynodeid==7' myprivateregistry.foo:5000/imagename:latest
```

will bringt up this error: `No such image: myprivateregistry.foo:5000/imagename:latest` because the credentials, which are valid btw, are not passed to the node.

Comment: Please mention what errors are you getting with this code.

Comment: I don't get any error. I just don't know how to use the docker-java API to add the mentioned flag. Did search doc and source code but did not find anything.

Comment: Is it fine if the registry auth is provided in your dockerClient object itself?

Comment: Building DockerClient object with `.withRegistryUsername(), .withRegistryPassword()` did not change anything.

Comment: What was the poblem with these two options, or you just got no output.

Comment: Have you tried all the ways mentioned here https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java#programmatic to specify the registry details.

Comment: I did, the command runs. Service is created and then fails cause it cannot download the image on my node. I assume registry authentication details are not sent to swarm agents cause the flag is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of docker-java `3.2.0-rc5` you can now specify authConfig to pull images from a private registry

```
        AuthConfig authConfig = new AuthConfig()
                .withUsername("testuser")
                .withPassword("testpassword")
                .withEmail("foo@bar.com")
                .withRegistryAddress("your.registry.address.here");

        dockerClient.createServiceCmd(new ServiceSpec()
                .withName(SERVICE_NAME)
                .withTaskTemplate(new TaskSpec()
                        .withContainerSpec(new ContainerSpec()
                                .withImage(DEFAULT_IMAGE))))
                .withAuthConfig(authConfig)
                .exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify registry auth details in `dockerClient` object itself in your code.

Check [this](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java#programmatic) out.

If it didn't worked. First verify whether the registry auth details you have are the correct one and manually try to pull docker image using docker cli.

Put registry config in `.docker/config.json` file and try to pull docker images. And then backtrace the issues.

Comment: Thanks, docker cli works, see question. I think either docker-java does not provide a way to pass the option/flag or I cannot find how.